# Making a serial number using excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Sorry guys, I reedited  this post to make my question clear.[image]

I need to use the **Model** and **Quantity** to make a column of serial number. I combine the model and quantity and manually drag down the cell(auto filled) to make the list, as you can see the quantity could be very large, can I use a formula to populate the serial number?

Comment: Use the & and concatenate them together - I would use IF() to choose the version depending on the size of the number...

Comment: I already used the & combine column A and B, can you tell me more detail about using IF()?

Comment: Do you need the serial number to be the same length (number of characters)? If so, consider a LEN() formula and then look up how to pad text. Combine with concactenate or & and it should work pretty smoothly.

Comment: Even though a formula can be formed to achieve this, we should be copying the formula down manually to the end of your serial number(s), this will be difficult especially when your quantity is high. IMHO this should be done with a VBA code, to have the results neatly at once.

Answer (score 0):

So, using IF() as used in cell C1:

```
=IF(B1="","Blank",IF(B1<100,A1&"000"&B1,IF(B1<1000,A1&"00"&B1,IF(B1<10000,A1&"0"&B1,"Check"))))
```

And to show it working:
[image: example]

You could copy / paste special values afterwards...

Comment: I know how to combine ColumnA and ColumnB, what I need is show every number. C1 for example, it is LTRS00015, and I need LTRS00001,LTRS00002,LTRS00003,...,LTRS00014,LTRS00015